# airflow icon legend - what is the meaning of a ring around a task in the webserver's treeview?

Tags: airflow, airflow-webserver

New to airflow here, and wondering if there's an icon legend in the [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/index.html) somewhere. I was not able to find.

More particularly, what's the meaning of a circle around a task in the webserver's treeview:
[image]

For example, in the `example_complex` example from the [getting started tutorial](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning is that the *tasks* with the black thicker border, can be unfolded on click and display downstream *tasks*. By default this will group and hide downstream tasks that were not started or even duplicated branches. It's like a UI helper to avoid showing too much information at once.

For example, if there are 10 tasks with a downstream task named **end**, it is likely that it will be displayed only once by default.

Example of default tree view:

[image: default tree view]

After clicking the node called: *"get_processable_"*

[image: clicking the node called: get_processable_]